# Die hard problem

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic, puzzle, word-problem

**Statement:**
You have a 11 litre and a 19 litre water container, each container has no markings except for that which gives you it's total volume. You also have a running tap. You must use the containers and the tap in such away as to exactly measure out 6 litres of water. How is this done? Can you generalize the solution?

Need your assistance to solve this question.

But I had solved similar question as shown below:

**Statement:**

You have a 3 and a 5 litre water container, each container has no markings except for that which gives you it's total volume. You also have a running tap. You must use the containers and the tap in such away as to exactly measure out 4 litres of water. How is this done?
Can you generalise the form of your answer?

**Answer:**

There are two ways to solve this, maybe the question could be modified to say the 5 litre can doesn't fit under the tap...

Number 1:
$\cdot$ Fill the 5 litre can from the tap

$\cdot$ Empty the 5 litre can into the 3 litre can - leaving 2 litres in the 5 litre can.

$\cdot$ Pour away the contents of the 3 litre can.

$\cdot$ Fill the 3 litre can with the 2 litres from the 5 litre can - leaving 2 litres in the 3 litre can.

$\cdot$ Fill the 5 litre can from the tap.

$\cdot$ Fill the remaining 1 litre space in the 3 litre can from the 5 litre can.

$\cdot$ Leaving 4 litres in the 5 litre can.

Number 2:

$\cdot $ Fill the 3 litre can from the tap.

$\cdot$ Empty the contents of the 3 litre can into the 5 litre can.

$\cdot$ Fill the 3 litre can from the tap.

$\cdot$ Empty the contents of the 3 litre can into the 5 litre can. - Leaving the 5 litre can full and 1 litre in the 3 litre can.

$\cdot$ Pour away the contents of the 5 litre can

$\cdot$ Pour the 1 litre from the 3 litre can into the 5 litre can.

$\cdot$ Fill the 3 litre can from the tap.

$\cdot$ Empty the contents of the 3 litre can into the 5 litre can.

$\cdot$ Leaving 4 litres in the 5 litre can.

Generalised Form:

We have two solutions above which both give the same answer of 3 litres. It turns out that if you make it algebraic the answer does not have the same form and it's sort of coincidence. Lets call the smaller container A and the lager B and work it through.

Number 1: Empty the 5 litre can into the 3 litre can - leaving 2 litres in the 5 litre can. ie $B - A$ in $B$ \
Fill the 3 litre can with the 2 litres from the 5 litre can - leaving 2 litres in the 3 litre can. As in space in A of $A - (B - A) = 2A - B$
Fill the remaining 1 litre space in the 3 litre can from the 5 litre can. Leaving 4 litres in the 5 litre can. So the amount in $B$ is $B - (2A - B)$ or $2B - 2A$

So the generalised form of solution 1 is $2B - 2A$ in $B$.

Number 2: Fill the 3 litre can from the tap. Empty the contents of the 3 litre can into the 5 litre can. Which gives us $B - A$ space in $B$.
Fill the 3 litre can from the tap. Empty the contents of the 3 litre can into the 5 litre can. - Leaving the 5 litre can full and 1 litre in the 3 litre can. ie. removing $(B - A)$ from $A$ leaves $A - (B - A)$ or $2A - B$ in $A$
Pour away the contents of the 5 litre can. Pour the 1 litre from the 3 litre can into the 5 litre can. ie $2A - B$ in $B$
Fill the 3 litre can from the tap. Empty the contents of the 3 litre can into the 5 litre can. Leaving 4 litres in the 5 litre can. ie $A + (2A - B)$ or $3A - B$ in $B$.

So the generalised form of solution 2 is $3A - B$ in $B$.

There are some restrictions, such as in solution 2; $2A < B$ ($2A$ must be less than $B$,) but other wise we can make up other puzzles like 5 Litres and 9 Litres to get 6 Litres. or 8 Litres. All exactly the same form.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Please edit your question with your attempts.

Comment: Take a look to Bezout's identity.

Comment: I had solved where I took a 5 litre and a 3 litre water container to measure out 6 litres of water. But that was easy.

Comment: There is a great Mathologer video on youtube about this problem [How not to Die Hard with Math](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Oef3MHYEC0)

Comment: Use informative titles. "Die hard problem" says nothing about the subject of the problem.

Comment: The general principle is: Fill B, Fill A from B so long until A is not full. Fill B and repeat. Algebraically this means:
 1. Set $X = 19$
 2. While $X > 11$ set $X = X-11$
 3. Set $X = 19-(11-X) = 8 + X$

Thus we get $19,8,16,5,13,2,10,18,7,15,4,12,1,9,17,6$

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Some (really just some?) of the achievable filling states are the ones marked below plus  by extending the arrow accordingly

[image]

Comment: (+1) nice interpretation :D

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.